# System won't restart after Windows Update. Is there a way to pull EFS files off the system?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, efs

I'm trying to fix a system where the user account was encrypted using Windows 10's cipher command.

The user tried to update Windows and it got stuck in a reboot loop. As Windows can't start, I cannot get at her files to copy them to another computer. I can't start Windows

Is there some way that I can get the credentials to load offline through the recorvery command or is fixing Windows the only option here?

Thanks.

Comment: The certificate would have had to be exported before these events happened in order to recover the files in a case like this.  Might be easier to resolve the reason the system will not boot, by uninstalling the pending updates, then to attempt to recover files at this point.

Comment: Following on from Ramhound, are you able to boot into safe mode?

Comment: Right now I'm not able to boot into safe mode so I need to keep plugging at this in the meantime I guess.